# Firebase Auth - Set session expiration

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

How can I set session expiration for a Firebase auth session? 
By default the session never expires.

I wish for the session to expire after 8 hours of inactivity.

I have read [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions) but cannot figure out how to set session expiration.

My code for signing in the user and performing tasks on sign in and sign out

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    //Signed in
  }else{
    //Signed out
  }
}
```

Thanks for all replies!
I have tried but cannot seem to get Firebase-admin to work.

Firebase-db.js

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

const databaseConnection = {
  serviceAccountFile: './serviceAccount.json',
  databaseURL: 'https://myProject.firebaseio.com/'
}

const serviceAccount = require(databaseConnection.serviceAccountFile)

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: databaseConnection.databaseURL
}, 'test')

const database = admin.database(app)

module.exports = database
```

sessionSignout.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')   
const database = require('../../firebase-db')
const admin = database.admin

exports.sessionSignout = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.pubsub
.schedule('*/15 * * * *')
.timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
.onRun(async (event) => {
  database.ref(`users`)
  .once('value', (usersSnapshots) => {
    usersSnapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      const uid = snapshot.key
      admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
    })
  })
}
```

I get error

> Error: function execution failed. Details: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

Comment: use custom auth claim and only allow a user to access data if it has the timestamp in last 8 hours. else don't allow access. it is somewhat session expiry ;)

Comment: or just simply revoke the session token using admin sdk. the link you have mentioned have the sample implementation

Comment: Hi Har Kal! Thank you for the reply! I will give it a try! Many thanks!

Comment: I found the error, see my complete code below. /K

Comment: change "const admin = database.admin" on line 3rd to "import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you linked says that you can use the Firebase Admin SDK to [revoke a user's refresh tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) in order to terminate their session.  This code must run on a backend you control, which means that you won't be able to do it in the client app.  The backend will need to know when the user became "inactive", by whatever definition of that you choose.  Wiring this all up is non-trivial, but possible.

Comment: Thank you Doug for the reply! I already have code in place to support presence awareness - I know if the user is logged in and when the user logged in! I will give this approach a try and update with example code! Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Doug! I am having trouble accessing firebase-app in a correct manner. Other than that I believe my code might work.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers! 
I just wanted to share my code for others to use.

I already had code in place to accommodate presence awareness.

index.js

```
import database from './firebase/firebase' //Firebase setup for client

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  //Handle login and redirect

  if (user) {
    //We are logged in
    addPresenceAwarenessListener()
  }else{
    ...
  }
}

const addPresenceAwarenessListener = () => {
  // Create a reference to the special '.info/connected' path in 
  // Realtime Database. This path returns `true` when connected
  // and `false` when disconnected.
  database.ref('.info/connected').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    // If we're not currently connected, don't do anything.
    if (snapshot.val() == false) {
      return
    }

    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

    //Push last login/logout to user profile
    const userLastLoginOutRef = database.ref(`users/${uid}`)
    userLastLoginOutRef.onDisconnect().update({lastLoginOut: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP})
    .then(() => { userLastLoginOutRef.update({lastLoginOut: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP}) })
  })
}
```

Session handling - expire sessions after *n* hours (setting "sessExp" in database)

firebase-db.js - Basic Firebase setup for cloud functions

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

const databaseConnection = {
  serviceAccountFile: './my-project.json',
  databaseURL: 'https://my-project.firebaseio.com/'
}

const serviceAccount = require(databaseConnection.serviceAccountFile)

const app = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: databaseConnection.databaseURL
}, 'remindMiNotifier')

const database = admin.database(app)
module.exports = database
```

sessionSignout.js - Signout user after a specific time period - if specified. Default to eternal session.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const moment = require('moment')
const database = require('../../firebase-db')
const admin = database.app

//Import enviroment variable config (.env)
require('dotenv').config()

//Export cron job - deploy: firebase deploy --only functions:sessionSignout
exports.sessionSignout = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.pubsub
.schedule('*/15 * * * *')
.timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
.onRun(async (event) => {
  //Start execution
  const now = moment()
  const defaultSessionTime = 0 //Eternal session

  //Get all users and calculate inactive time - time since last login
  let logoutUsersArray = []
  await database.ref(`users`)
  .once('value', (usersSnapshots) => {
    usersSnapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      const userData = snapshot.val()
      const lastLoginOut = (userData.lastLoginOut) ? userData.lastLoginOut : 0
      //Only process users that has a login/out time stamp
      if(lastLoginOut > 0){
        const userSessionTime = (userData.sessExp) ? userData.sessExp : defaultSessionTime
        const hoursSinceLastLoginOut = now.diff(lastLoginOut, 'hours')
        const logoutUser = ( userSessionTime > 0 && (hoursSinceLastLoginOut > userSessionTime) )

        if(logoutUser){
          const userId = snapshot.key
          const userName = (userData.alias) ? userData.alias : userData.displayName
          const email = (userData.email) ? userData.email : ''
          const userObject = {
            userId,
            userName,
            email,
            lastLoginOut,
            diffHours: now.diff(lastLoginOut, 'hours')
          }
          logoutUsersArray.push(userObject)
        }
      }
    })
  })
  console.log('logoutUsersArray', logoutUsersArray)

  //Collect all promises to carry out 
  let myPromises = []

  // Revoke all refresh tokens for each user
  logoutUsersArray.forEach((logoutUser) => {
    const uid = logoutUser.userId
    myPromises.push(
      admin.auth().revokeRefreshTokens(uid)
      .then(() => {
        return admin.auth().getUser(uid)
      })
      .then((userRecord) => {
        return new Date(userRecord.tokensValidAfterTime).getTime() / 1000
      })
      .then((timestamp) => {
        // Retrieve the timestamp of the revocation, in seconds since the epoch.
        console.log('Tokens revoked at: ', timestamp)
        return Promise.resolve(true)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error', err)
        return Promise.reject(err)
      })
    )
  })

  //Execute promises
  console.log('Execute promises')
  return Promise.all(myPromises)
  .then(() => Promise.resolve(true))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error', err)
    return Promise.reject(err)
  })

})//End sessionSignout
```

[Documentation on firebase-admin can be found here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Database.html#app)